# Cannot find Dapper.dll when running 'dotnet test'

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dll, xunit, dapper

I am trying to run a C# test using `dotnet test` to test a project (targets to .NET 6.0) which uses Dapper, and I am getting the following error message:

```
D:\dev\>dotnet test
  Determining projects to restore...
  All projects are up-to-date for restore.
  ProjectRepository -> D:\dev\project1\ProjectRepository\bin\Debug\net6.0\ProjectRepository.dll
  ProjectCommon -> D:\dev\project1\ProjectCommon\bin\Debug\net6.0\ProjectCommon.dll
Test run for D:\dev\project1\ProjectCommon\bin\Debug\net6.0\ProjectCommon.dll (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0)
Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 17.5.0 (x64)
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Starting test execution, please wait...
A total of 1 test files matched the specified pattern.
Testhost process for source(s) 'D:\dev\project1\ProjectCommon\bin\Debug\net6.0\ProjectCommon.dll' exited with error: Error:
  An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (ProjectCommon.deps.json) was not found:
    package: 'Dapper', version: '2.0.78'
    path: 'lib/net5.0/Dapper.dll'
. Please check the diagnostic logs for more information.

Test Run Aborted.
  ProjectCommonTest -> D:\dev\project1\ProjectCommonTest\bin\Debug\net6.0\ProjectCommonTest.dll
Test run for D:\dev\project1\ProjectCommonTest\bin\Debug\net6.0\ProjectCommonTest.dll (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0)
Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 17.5.0 (x64)
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Starting test execution, please wait...
A total of 1 test files matched the specified pattern.

Passed!  - Failed:     0, Passed:     1, Skipped:     0, Total:     1, Duration: < 1 ms - ProjectCommonTest.dll (net6.0)
```

I did search for 'Dapper.dll' and it does exists but it does not exists in path `lib/net5.0/Dapper.dll`

I have checked the diagnostic logs but could not find any helpful information. Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: How do you reference Dapper in your project(s)? Nuget reference? Can you provide a [mre] of your csproj files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, we found that the project being tested has xUnit package installed, remove xUnit from the project fixed the issue.

These two things looks unrelated but it IS indeed has some magic behind them.